# rake pass parameters to dependent tasks

Tags: ruby, rake

Here is the current way I run rak dependent tasks

```
task :test => [:prepare_testdir,:run_tests]
```

currently there is no parameters for these two dependent tasks. But I need to add parameters to one of tasks. It should be running like on command line

```
rake prepare_testdir[mydir]
```

How do I pass this new parameter to this

```
task :test => [:prepare_testdir,:run_tests]
```

I have tried

```
task :test => [:prepare_testdir[mydir],:run_tests]
```

and

```
 task :test => [:prepare_testdir['mydir'],:run_tests]
```

both are not working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Inside the rake file

```
task :test, [:dir] => [:prepare_testdir] do |t,args|
  puts args.inspect # {:dir=>"foo"}
end

task :prepare_testdir, :dir do |t, args|
  puts args.inspect # {:dir=>"foo"}
end
```

Invocation

```
rake test[foo]
```

Comment: This is actually a little different because you have changed the API of the `test` task.